# How to use Xtemplate inside sencha architect?

Tags: extjs, touch

I'm developing a web app using sencha touch and I'm using sencha architect, I want to add a condition to my list itemtpl to view difference in customer's balance:

```
balance>=0 --> green

balance<0  --> red
```

This is my basic itemtpl:

```
<table width="100%"><tr>
    <td>{c_name}</td>
    <td width="95px">
         <div style="width:95px;height:100%;background:#088cfc;text-align:center;color:#fff;">{balance}</div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I add xtemplate **using sencha architect IDE** and link it to my list?

thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I wanted an answer to the same problem when dealing with how to "Use an XTemplate in Architect" which is what the title states and the Answer given does not actually show a beginning user an answer on how to do this in Architect in my opinion.

So the steps are:

1. So add your component to the Architect canvas or within what ever component you are using.
2. Next go to the Configs list and find the entry for 'Process Config' and click the plus sign
   [image]
3. next you will get a function that allows you to update and process any of the current Config settings or add your own.  My function is called 'processMyView' (I am using a dataview for my example, ergo the name)
4. add some javascript that creates the 'tpl'
5. ensure you return the 'config' parameter at the end of the function
   [image]

In my example I had a list of Documents with title and owner and so the end result will look like this.

[image]

In the end anytime you are being frustrated by Architect, this may be one of the approaches you can take to get around the IDE's rigidity for a Config setting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually using XTemplate in architect just use `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of '<' and '>' in your condition:

if balance>0 ==> use:  if balance > 0 see below:

```
<table width="100%"><tr>
    <td>{c_name}</td>
    <td width="95px">
        <tpl if="balance &gt; 0"> 
         <div style="border-radius:5px;;width:95px;height:100%;background:#088cfc;text-align:center;color:#fff;font-size:12px;height:23px;padding-top:4px;">{balance} ₪</div>
        </tpl> 
        <tpl if="balance &lt; 0"> 
         <div style="border-radius:5px;;width:95px;height:100%;background:#f00;text-align:center;color:#fff;font-size:12px;height:23px;padding-top:4px;">{balance} ₪</div>
        </tpl> 
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's the answer, just use the ascii code of '<' and '>'  I'll put them here with spaces '& g t ;' and '& l t ;'